# Find all files depending on a given file in a webpack JS with ES6 modules

Tags: javascript, webpack, es6-modules

I'm looking for a way to find all files that depend on a given JS file. My project is using ES6 modules and webpack. I had a look at [node-dependency-tree](https://github.com/dependents/node-dependency-tree) but it is only doing the opposite: listing all files that a given file depends on.

My ultimate goal is to facilitate renaming/moving a file in a project by updating all files that import it.

Comment: You can use node-dependency-tree for each file, or (easier) look for files that have a specific import string, with `find`

Comment: Can't you just grep your entire project to see who is importing that JS module?